How to DSolve[{-0.8*y'[x]*y''[x]/(1 + (y'[x])^2)^1.4 == 0.77781490, y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1}, y[x], x]
How can I solve this equation using DSolve in Mathematica?
DSolve[{-0.8*y'[x]*y''[x]/(1 + (y'[x])^2)^1.4 == 0.77781490, 
  y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1}, y[x], x] 


My first thought was you should use exact numbers with DSolve, but when I noticed (1 + (y'[x])^2)^1.4, I changed that idea to, "Would NDSolve[] be a good enough choice?"

Or DSolve[{-0.8*y'[x]*y''[x]/(1 + (y'[x])^2)^1.4 == 0.77781490(*,y[0]==0,   y[1]==1*)}, y[x], x] and solve the BCs with FindRoot[] maybe.

Maple 2024 produces two complicated  solutions difficult to work with. The function y[x] may be convex, then y'[x]>=0 and y''[x]>=0 , or the one may be concave, then both are non-positive.,

May be useful. Putting y'[x]->u[x], we have DSolve[-4/5*u[x]*u'[x]/(1 + (u[x])^2)^(7/5) == 77781490/10^(8), u[x],    x] // InputForm which results in {{u[x] -> -Sqrt[-1 + (100000000000000000*Sqrt[10])/        (7778149*x - 8000000*C[1])^(5/2)]},   {u[x] -> Sqrt[-1 + (100000000000000000*Sqrt[10])/       (7778149*x - 8000000*C[1])^(5/2)]}}. Then we can find the general solution y[x] by integration..

There was no other, perhaps human-readable and search engine index-able way of titling your question?

Drop the BCs and solve the for the general solution with rationalized numbers; then solve the BCs with FindRoot[]. The general solution has two solutions; the second one could not satisfy the BCs, it seemed.
dsol = DSolve[{
    -4/5*y'[x]*y''[x]/(1 + (y'[x])^2)^(7/5) == a
    (*,y[0]==0,y[1]==1*)
    }, y[x], x, GeneratedParameters -> c];

{y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1} /. (First@dsol /. x -> 0) /. (First@dsol /. 
     x -> 1) /. {a -> 7778149/10000000};
bcsol = FindRoot[%, {{c[1], 1.6}, {c[2], 1.004}}];

bvpsol = First@dsol /. {a -> 0.7778149} /. bcsol
(*
{y[x] -> (-4.27511 + 
     3.14085 I) - (7.69 ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 
        3.88907 x) Sqrt[-1 + (
       25 Sqrt[5])/((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/2)]
       Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), -(1/10), 9/
       10, ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/2)/(
       25 Sqrt[5])])/(Sqrt[
     25 Sqrt[5] - ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/2)])}
*)

Check BC residuals:
{y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1} /. Equal -> Subtract /.
  (bvpsol /. x -> 0) /. (bvpsol /. x -> 1)
(*
{2.66454*10^-15 + 1.33227*10^-15 I,
 4.44089*10^-15 - 1.77636*10^-15 I}
*)


In the above it should be (1 + (y'[x])^2)^(7/5) instead of (1 + (y'[x])^2)^(7/45) (see the question), so you don't solve the problem under consideration.

@user64494 Fixednow. Thanks.

Too long for a comment. It seems there is  a second (conjugate) solution. Indeed,
dsol = DSolve[{-4/5*y'[x]*y''[x]/(1 + (y'[x])^2)^(7/5) == a
(*,y[0]==0,y[1]==1*)}, y[x], x, GeneratedParameters -> c];
{y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1} /. (First@dsol /. x -> 0) /. (First@dsol /. 
 x -> 1) /. {a -> 7778149/10000000};
bcsol1 = FindRoot[%, {{c[1], -1.6}, {c[2], -1.004}}]


c[1] -> 1.29723 + 0.538128 I, c[2] -> -4.27511 - 3.14085 I}

bvpsol1 = First@dsol /. {a -> 0.7778149} /. bcsol1


{y[x] -> (-4.27511 -  3.14085 I) - (7.69 ((-5.18893 - 2.15251 I) +  3.88907 x) Sqrt[-1 + ( 25 Sqrt[5])/((-5.18893 - 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/2)] Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), -(1/10), 9/ 10, ((-5.18893 - 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/2)/( 25 Sqrt[5])])/(Sqrt[ 25 Sqrt[5] - ((-5.18893 - 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/2)])}

{y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1} /. Equal -> Subtract /.
  (bvpsol1 /. x -> 0) /. (bvpsol1 /. x -> 1)


{-8.88178*10^-16 + 2.66454*10^-15 I,  8.88178*10^-16 - 4.44089*10^-16 I}

Addition. There are problems with the verification of the solutions. Let us start from yours.
-0.8*y'[x]*y''[x]/(1 + (y'[x])^2)^1.4 -    0.77781490 /. 
{y[x] -> (-4.27511 + 
   3.14085 I) - (7.69 ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 
      3.88907 x) Sqrt[-1 + (25 Sqrt[5])/((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 
          3.88907 x)^(5/2)] Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), -(1/10), 
     9/10, ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/2)/(25 Sqrt[
         5])])/(Sqrt[
    25 Sqrt[5] - ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/2)]), 
y'[x] -> 
D[(-4.27511 + 
    3.14085 I) - (7.69 ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 
       3.88907 x) Sqrt[-1 + (25 Sqrt[
           5])/((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/
           2)] Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), -(1/10), 
      9/10, ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/2)/(25 Sqrt[
          5])])/(Sqrt[
     25 Sqrt[5] - ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/2)]), 
 x], y''[x] -> 
D[(-4.27511 + 
    3.14085 I) - (7.69 ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 
       3.88907 x) Sqrt[-1 + (25 Sqrt[
           5])/((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/
           2)] Hypergeometric2F1[-(1/2), -(1/10), 
      9/10, ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/2)/(25 Sqrt[
          5])])/(Sqrt[
     25 Sqrt[5] - ((-5.18893 + 2.15251 I) + 3.88907 x)^(5/
         2)]), {x, 2}]};
N[Table[%, {x, 0, 1, 0.2}], 15]


{-1.40708 - 0.457185 I, -1.40708 - 0.457186 I, -1.40708 -  0.457187 I, -1.40708 - 0.457187 I, -1.40708 -  0.457188 I, -1.40708 - 0.457188 I}

The same for mine produces

{-1.40708+0.457185 I,-1.40708+0.457186 I,-1.40708+0.457187 I,-1.40708+0.457187 I,-1.40708+0.457188 I,-1.40708+0.457188 I}

Too much for round-off errors.
